# Protein modification and ATP consumption

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, energy

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-translational_modification#Non-enzymatic_additions_in_vivo) there exists a lot of ways to modify a protein (post-translationally). Just to mention few: phosphorylation, dephosphorylation, glycosylation... While phosphorylation requires an ATP molecule, the reverse reaction, dephosphorylation, does not.

How about the other process?

Do all modification respect this scheme (i.e. one transformation consumes ATP but the reverse transformation does not)?

If not, I am particularly interested to know if one transformation and its reverse transformation both requires ATP.

Thank you

Comment: ATP is adenosine triphosphate. The reason protein phosphorylation usually consumes ATP is because the ATP contains the donor phosphate group. Some other post-translational modifications have ATP-dependent steps (e.g. ubiquitination), but not most (e.g. acetylation). As you say, there are a lot of ways to modify a protein post-translationally, so why not look at the wikipedia pages for the various modifications to see which ones have steps that require ATP?

Comment: I don't think there are any which have direct ATP involvement in both steps. Indirect dependence may be there.